# python daily data from minute by minute data

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe with index= datetime.datetime minute by minute. I want to run a loop where for each iteration, I want to just take the data for a given day. is there a better way to do this apart from the following:

```
data['index_date'] = data['index'].apply(lambda dt: datetime.datetime(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, 0,0))

days= data['index_date'].unique()

for day is days:
    data_day= data[data['index_date']==day]
```

Just a sample of what "data" df looks like:

```
>>> data
Out[8]: 
         index             90    180
2016-01-04 02:30:00-05:00 1.000 1.000
2016-01-04 02:31:00-05:00 1.000 1.000
2016-01-04 02:32:00-05:00 1.000 1.000
2016-01-04 02:33:00-05:00 1.000 1.000
2016-01-04 02:34:00-05:00 1.000 1.000

...                         ...   ...
2016-07-26 12:51:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
2016-07-26 12:52:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
2016-07-26 12:53:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
2016-07-26 12:54:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
2016-07-26 12:55:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
2016-07-26 12:56:00-04:00 1.000 1.000
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `data_day`?  Do you want an average?  All of them?  If you want all them, why are you grouping at all?  Usually you want to group in order to aggregate or transform.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I will do different kinds of stuff. For starters, I need to do PCA analysis on data for each day and get the first eigenvector.

Comment: Then that's what you pass to the apply function in my answer.

Comment: OK, got it. So seems like there is not a simpler way to get all of the data if I needed for some other purpose.

Comment: There are many clever things to be done.  However, they are often very specific to the problem.

Comment: lets say the problem is to divide the whole timeseries into a panel/dictionary of different dataframes with one dataframe for each day.

Comment: edited my answer.  hopefully that helps

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful. Accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider `df`

```
n = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=n, freq='T'),
                    90: np.random.rand(n) * 10,
                    100: np.random.randn(n) * 100})
```

---

Then you can get a dictionary of days

```
g = df.set_index('index').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))
d = {k: v for k, v in g}
```

---

Or a panel

```
p = pd.Panel(d)
```

---

Or a dataframe

```
dfg = pd.concat(d.values, keys=d.keys())
```

Comment: @dayum you'll have to do some work to show what you want.